# Anchor Tags on Embedded Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce

We have a visualforce page embedded on our opportunity layout that is quite long and as such we're placing anchor tags on the page for quicker navigation. Thus, we have a series of links that are directed to anchor tags later in the page, nothing fancy, just  -> .

When these links are clicked, instead of navigating further down the page to where the anchor tag is, nothing happens. My instinct tells me it may have to do with the embedded/iframe nature, but I can't find anything concrete. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could just put an anchor just above your apex:pageBlockSection tags:

```
<a id="myAnchor"></a>
```

Then you'd have to build a simple nav. at the top of the page pointing to your anchors:

```
<a href="#myAnchor"></a>
```

Comment: Thats what we're doing: <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#intro"><h4>Intro</h4></a> is the button and <div class="panel-heading thePanelHeading">
                                <a name="intro"></a>
                                <h2 class="sectionTitle">Intro <i class="fa fa-coffee" aria-hidden="true"></i></h2>
                            </div> is where the anchor lies

Comment: @GeorgeAlbrecht Are you in development mode

Comment: nope. Since the embedded page is in edit mode however do you think that could be it?

Comment: @George Albrecht check this out ..https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000098nXIAQ